# Unable to to parse the payload and extract data from Slack back to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api

Disclaimer, I am new to GAS and admittedly brute forcing my way into trying to make something work. If someone has a pointer, I'd really appreciate it.

Goal: was to post to slack when someone submits a form. User in slack clicks a button. That data is recorded back onto sheets into a specific column and in the row related to the form content that was submitted.

Latest progress: able to post a message to slack when someone submits a form which includes an interactive (approve / reject) message. Once you click the button, I'm able to send confirmation to Slack with a custom message that the payload has been received. Payload is in the sheets in the top row, first column, but I'm unable to parse the value correctly.  Pretty certain I need to set the range and then set the values, using some array notation.  I've tried some difficult code and the best I could do was post the timestamp back to Sheets.

Here's the code and payload.  I'd really appreciate any tips.

```
       function postToSlack() {
        var payload = {

        "text": "Take a look at this form submitted.",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": "press a button",
                "fallback": "You are unable to make a selection",
                "callback_id": "error",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "review",
                        "text": "approve",
                        "style": "primary",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "approve",
                        "action_id": "button",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "review",
                        "text": "need more info",
                        "style": "danger",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "reject",
                        "action_id": "button"


                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

        var options = {
            'method': 'post',
            'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
        }

        var slackWebookURL = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX"
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebookURL, options);
    }



       function doPost(e) {
        Logger.log("I was called")
        if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
            Logger.log(e.parameter);
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet ID")
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
        sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))

      return ContentService.createTextOutput(' Thanks for reviewing! ');
    }
```

```
{"parameter":{"payload":"{\"type\":\"interactive_message\",\"actions\":[{\"name\":\"review\",\"type\":\"button\",\"value\":\"approve\"}],\"callback_id\":\"error\",\"team\":{\"id\":\"***********\",\"domain\":\"slackname-global\"},\"channel\":{\"id\":\"********\",\"name\":\"testchannel\"},\"user\":{\"id\":\"U013FTGA30D\",\"name\":\"first.last\"},\"action_ts\":\"15998273855.588360\",\"message_ts\":\"159344554.002200\",\"attachment_id\":\"1\",\"token\":\"Vksfhjah3yXSvdHHn9H7RyBF\",\"is_app_unfurl\":false,\"original_message\":{\"type\":\"message\",\"subtype\":\"bot_message\",\"text\":\"Please review submission.\",\"ts\":\"1590853854.002200\",\"bot_id\":\"B014dfE8MU\",\"attachments\":[{\"callback_id\":\"error\",\"fallback\":\"You are unable to make a selection\",\"text\":\"press the appropriate button\",\"id\":1,\"color\":\"3AA3E3\",\"actions\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"review\",\"text\":\"approve\",\"type\":\"button\",\"value\":\"approve\",\"style\":\"primary\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"review\",\"text\":\"need more info\",\"type\":\"button\",\"value\":\"reject\",\"style\":\"danger\"}]}]},\"response_url\":\"https:\\/\\/hooks.slack.com\\/actions\\/T013PEGKE0L\\/1153573701509\\/3aLa2Ece7ZiRFIJ4oTWJCECC\",\"trigger_id\":\"1178789486208.1125492660020.527c043df757d682913d2e0501f30026\"}"},"queryString":"","
```

```
"postData":{"contents":"payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive_message%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22review%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22approve%22%7D%5D%2C%22callback_id%22%3A%22error%22%2C%22team%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22T013PEGKE0L%22%2C%22domain%22%3A%22shino-global%22%7D%2C%22channel%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22C014PMG7VU4%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22gas%22%7D%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22U013FTGA30D%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22slack.name%22%7D%2C%22action_ts%22%3A%221590853855.588360%22%2C%22message_ts%22%3A%221590853854.002200%22%2C%22attachment_id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22Vk4deddddayXSvdHHn9H7RyBF%22%2C%22is_app_unfurl%22%3Afalse%2C%22original_message%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22message%22%2C%22subtype%22%3A%22bot_message%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Name%21+Please+review+submission.%22%2C%22ts%22%3A%221590853854.002200%22%2C%22bot_id%22%3A%22B014AQ2Q8MU%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22callback_id%22%3A%22error%22%2C%22fallback%22%3A%22You+are+unable+to+make+a+selection%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22press+the+appropriate+button%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22color%22%3A%223AA3E3%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22review%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22approve%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22approve%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22primary%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22review%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22need+more+info%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22reject%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22danger%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22response_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fhooks.slack.com%5C%2Factions%5C%2FT013PEGKE0L%5C%2F1153571101509%5C%2F3aLa2Ece7ZiRFIJ4oTWJCECC%22%2C%22trigger_id%22%3A%221178789486208.1125492660020.527c043df757d682913d2e0501f30026%22%7D","length":1699,"name":"postData","type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"contextPath":"","contentLength":1699}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I'm unable to parse the value correctly.`?

Comment: Guys, is there are contest / homework assignment we are not aware of? I've just finished answering a question with 99% same code for `doPost` and the same premise of posting a message to Slack?

Comment: I can successfully post to slack with a doPost function.  The trouble is extracting data from the payload from Slack to sheets.  The value, meaning getting data related to the button pressed in an interactive message within Slack.

Comment: I made this example app for implementing Slack on GAS. It may be helpful: https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slack-sample-app-gas